# Showing $\left(\sin(\frac\pi4-x)-\sin(\frac\pi4+x)\right)\left(\sin(\frac\pi4-x)+\sin(\frac\pi4+x)\right)=0$ if and only if $\sin x\cos x=0$

Tags: trigonometry

$$\left(\sin\left(\frac \pi 4 -x \right) - \sin\left(\frac \pi 4 +x \right)\right)\left(\sin\left(\frac \pi 4 -x \right) + \sin\left(\frac \pi 4 +x \right)\right)=0\iff \sin x \cos x =0$$

Meet this solution in examples for exam, and don't understand where I can find steps between those steps. Maybe, i trying think in this way:
$$(\sin\left(\frac \pi 4 -x \right))^2 - (\sin\left(\frac \pi 4 +x \right))^2 = \cos2(something)$$

In prev same tasks, they used double angles formules and reduction formules.

Comment: Break the angles from sine addition formula. Also, you should show your attempt.

Comment: If this is in preparation for an exam, then you must have *some* idea of tools or techniques that might have been used. Please [edit the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4134808/edit) to describe them. This information helps people tailor their responses to best serve you without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques above your skill level.

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta Thank you, i m edit question.

Comment: @Blue Thank you, i m edit question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break the angles from sine addition formula

NOTE : $\sin(\pi/4 - x) = 1/\sqrt2(\cos x - \sin x)$ and $\sin(\pi/4 + x) = 1/\sqrt2(\cos x + \sin x)$

$\iff\left(\sin\left(\frac \pi 4 -x \right) - \sin\left(\frac \pi 4 +x \right)\right)\left(\sin\left(\frac \pi 4 -x \right) + \sin\left(\frac \pi 4 +x \right)\right)=0$

$\iff\sin^2(\frac \pi 4 -x) - \sin^2(\frac \pi 4 +x) = 0$

$\iff-2\sin x\cos x = 0$

$\iff\sin x\cos x  = 0$

Comment: Use a backslash before `sin` or `cos` in Mathjax

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks